# Can't add device to Azure Active Directory because it has two Object IDs

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, hybrid

When I try to add the device looping through a txt file, it says its already a member. When I check the members in the group, nothing changes. From what I've researched, this is due to hybrid setup with on-prem and Azure AD, but I would like to add the devices to the Azure group.

```
$azgroup = "myGroup"
$machines = get-content ".\deviceList.txt"

write-host "Getting Object ID of group.." -ForegroundColor Green
$objid = (get-azureadgroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$azgroup'" ).objectid
write-host "Getting group members (We dont want duplicates!).." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objid -all $true | select displayname

foreach ($machine in $machines) {
    $refid = Get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$machine'"
    $result = ""
    $result =  ($members -match $machine)
    if($result -eq ""){
        try{
            Write-host "Adding " $refid.displayname -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objid -RefObjectId $refid.objectid[0]
            }
        catch{
            write-host "An error occured for " $refid.displayname  -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
        else
        {
            write-host $machine " is already a member" -ForegroundColor Green
        }

}
```

I tried treating the specific ObjectID as an array but neither worked to add to Azure AD group

```
Add-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $objid -RefObjectId $refid.objectid[0]
```

If the AzureAD module doesn't work within a hybrid infrastructure, is there any way to bulk add devices to a group in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution. Ok so due to each device having more than one reference IDs, I just treated like an array. This is the part of my code I had to change:

```
[String]$refid = (Get-AzureADDevice -Filter "DisplayName eq '$machine'")[0].ObjectId
```

I misplaced the my index ([0]) and placed it after the property, not before it. Then I made sure it outputed a string for good measure, although you can check this with the .gettype() method. Because the on-premise DC and Azure sync, you can use these Device reference IDs interchangeably. It also didnt help outputting a custom error at first, thats what I get for copy-pasting part of someone else's code...